# Log Shipping between 2 AGs

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, log-shipping, disaster-recovery

I'm having one AG with two nodes (active-passive) in one data center and another AG with two nodes (active-passive) in a different data center.

I need to have log shipping enabled between these two setups, so that a DR situation can be handled.

Most articles are advising to have 1 node in DR. however, for HA, i need to have a AG in DR.

So, with this config, can log shipping be achieved? can you please guide on how to achieve that as well?

Thanks

Comment: What edition of SQL Server 2016?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, log-shipping would not work in your case (AG1 ot AG2), due to following reasons.

1. Database cannot be restored while it's already part of AG/Mirroring
2. Basically, Log-shipping does backups on primary replica, and restores on secondary replica with defined interval time

**Log-Shipping** would be good choice when **Secondary** replica in Log shipping topology is **standalone** and same version as primary SQL Instance. i.e. Your Data-center-1 AG act as primary replica and Standalone Instance at Data-center-2 act as secondary replica.

While you implementing Log-shipping for a Database that is already part of AG, you need to ensure that the **[Backup preference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-backup-on-availability-replicas-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)** cannot be set to secondary within AG as the log-shipping cannot work with secondary backup copies from AG. In your case AG of Data-center-1.

Since you already have Availability Groups in-place with SQL 2016 in two sub-nets, [distributed AG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017) might be correct solution.

---

You may follow these reference in either case:
[Distributed Availability Groups](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5053/setup-and-implement-sql-server-2016-always-on-distributed-availability-groups/)
[Log-shipping from AG Database](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/step-by-step-configuring-alwayson-with-log-shipping)